# Diksha Mantras in Ramanandi Sampradaya

Tags: mantras, sri-vaishnava, ramanujacharya, ramanandi, srisampraday

In Sri Sampradaya three mantras are given during diksha(Ashtakshari, Dvaya and Charam). Are three mantras also given in Ramanandi Sampradaya?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In Moolamantra(Ashtakshari) Ram Mantra is given. Dvaya mantra and Charam mantra are also given.